# tee and pipelines inside a bash script

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr, tee

i need to redirect stout and stderr in bash each to separate file. 
  well i completed this command:

```
  ((/usr/bin/java -jar /opt/SEOC2/seoc2.jar 2>&1 1>&3 | tee --append /opt/SEOC2/log/err.log) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee --append /opt/SEOC2/log/app.log) >> /opt/SEOC2/log/combined.log 2>&1  &
```

which works fine running from a **command line**.

trying to put the very same command into **bash script**

```
 ...
 12 cmd="(($run -jar $cmd 2>&1 1>&3 | tee --append $err) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee --append $log) >> $combined 2>&1"
 ...
 30                 echo -e "Starting servis..." 
 31                 $cmd &
 32                 pid=`ps -eo pid,args | grep seoc2.jar | grep -v grep | cut -c1-6`
 33                 if [ ! -z $pid ]; then
 ...
```

leads to error like this:

```
   root@operator:/opt/SEOC2# seoc2 start
   Starting servis...
   /usr/local/bin/seoc2: line 31: ((/usr/bin/java: dir or file doesn't exist
```

tried to cover this command by $( ), ` ` etc but with no effect at all :(

any suggestion or advice would be very appreciated, playing around for hours already :/

thanx a lot
Rene

Comment: Can you please post what you typed at the bash prompt to **invoke** the failing script, and show where you invoked it from (i.e. what was the current directory when you tired to run the script)

Comment: Do you need that entire pipeline in a single variable? The problem is that the quoted string causes the shell to not interpret the parentheses as shell syntax, but as literal characters in the string.  Simplest would be to just write the command out on line 31. `eval $cmd` would work, but is *not* recommended.

Comment: @JoshGreife isn't what are you asking for in the last gray box from my original post? i.e. 
skript is located in /opt/SEOC2
but should be able to run from anywhere
$err, $log, $combined are absolute path locations to /opt/SEOC2/log/
in this example i run it from /opt/SEOC2

Comment: ok, wasn't sure about the absolute locations.  Thought it might be relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you store the whole command line in a variable you have to use `eval` to execute it:

```
cmd="(($run -jar $cmd 2>&1 1>&3 | tee --append $err) 3>&1 1>&2 | tee --append $log) >> $combined 2>&1"
...
eval $cmd &
```

Comment: this hint seems to work well, although it generates ps tree like this:
<pre>
15583 pts/0    S      0:00 /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/seoc2 start
15585 pts/0    S      0:00  \_ /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/seoc2 start
15586 pts/0    S      0:00      \_ /bin/bash /usr/local/bin/seoc2 start
15588 pts/0    Sl     1:41      |   \_ /usr/bin/java -jar /opt/SEOC2/seoc2.jar
</pre>
but it doesn't effect the functionality, it realy works!
thanks a lot.
R

Comment: @user1062331: Those extra processes are not caused by the `eval` but by the parentheses. Each level of `()` will create a subshell.